# How to setup IPv6 on ubuntu host with two VMs

Tags: networking, ipv6, virtualization

I want to setup IPv6 network with two VMs(virtual box) on a ubuntu 12.04 host. One VM is backtrack and second is window XP. I want to know that how can i setup a fully IPv6 network so that i can communicate form backtrack to XP on virtual box network attached in bridged adapter mode, all traffic from backtrack to XP should goes through Ubuntu host.
is it also possible to configure ubuntu host as a DHCPv6 server so that it serve IPv6 to VMs automatically and able to communicate.
I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinXP does support IPv6, but you are required to have SP2 and you must manually add/install the protocol, and it does NOT support DHCPv6....use Win7 instead, as IPv6 is native...you will be much happier in your testing.

I have setup many similar scenarios as you are asking about on VMware workstation, but I have no experience w/virtual box, but I suspect it will work just fine.

hth...Jeff Carrell